PCIe MMIO Poor Access Performance
I'm testing my FPGA with PCIE4.0 X16 on Intel Xeon 6438Y+, the theoretical bandwidth is 32 GBps per direction. If I use DMA method to perform access, it can be achieved to 27GBps, which is quite reasonable. But when I try to use MMIO to access BAR space, the highest bandwidth is only 3.75 GBps.
I have tried consecutive vmovntdqa, vmovapd, movdir64b, memcpy(), and I use ioremap_wc() in kernel driver to map a 4MB Write Combine space.
my code is very similar to Poor MMIO performance with non-temporal loads on Intel Xeon
/* iobench.cpp */

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const size_t sz = 4 * 1024 * 1024; /* 4 MB */

    int sysfs_fd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (sysfs_fd == -1) assert_perror(errno);

    void* src = mmap(nullptr, sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sysfs_fd, 0);

    if (src == (void*)-1) assert_perror(errno);
    if (close(sysfs_fd) == -1) assert_perror(errno);

    char* dst = static_cast<char*>(aligned_alloc(4096, sz));
    assert(dst != nullptr);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    memcpy(dst, src, sz);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    float duration_sec = std::chrono::duration<float>(end - begin).count();
    float speed = sz / duration_sec / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
    std::cout << speed << " GB/s\n";

    if (munmap(src, sz) == -1) assert_perror(errno);
}


MMIO accesses from the CPU are not pipelined. Each access has to go from the CPU all the way to the device and the response returned to the CPU before the next access can start. This can take hundreds of nanoseconds for each 8- or 16-byte access. I'm very surprised you get as much bandwidth as you say.

You use UIO instead of raw access. Have you tried to eliminate that and see if it helps?
